# mouseListener: combination of press, click and drag

Tags: java, awt

I do use `java.awt.event` package. I need to perform an action (zoom an image), if: the middle mouse button is pressed, left/right button is clicked (middle one is still pressed) and mouse is dragged (middle button is still pressed). How to combine events? My code is:

```
package myPackage;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

public class myImageMouseListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener {
  ...
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // insert condition here?
    System.out.println("mousePressed " + e.getButton());
  }

  ...
}
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: You're looking to capture more complex mouse gestures. I recommend searching the internet for examples of that.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use your GUI if I had to do the mouse gymnastics you describe.  The [MouseEvent class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) has BUTTON1 (left button), BUTTON2 (center button), and BUTTON3 (right button) static int fields to be used with the getButton method.

Comment: Hi @GilbertLeBlanc, I know about buttons. I just can not get combined event if mouse is pressed and clicked at the same time

Answer (score 0):

So the right answer seems to be `int getModifiersEx()`, which I have found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). Now if I holds middle button + click left/right button and drag the mouse (middle button is still pressed), zooming is performed. Then my code looks like:

```
  private GLSWTImageViewer imageViewer;
  
  private int lastX;
  private int lastY;
  private boolean move;
  private boolean zoom;

  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
  {
    ...
    if (zoom) {
      int diffY = 0;
      diffY = lastY - e.getY();
      if (diffY > 0) {
        imageViewer.zoomIn();
        lastY = e.getY();
      }
      if (diffY < 0) {
        imageViewer.zoomOut();
        lastY = e.getY();
      }
    }
  }
  ...
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    //if middlebutton is pressed and left/right button clicked:
    if (e.getModifiersEx()==2048) {
      zoom = true;
    }    
  }
  ...
  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent aerg0)
  {
    ...    
    //if middle button is clicked:
    if (aerg0.getButton()==2) {
      zoom = false;
    }
  }
```